# How to restore a database from the SQL 2008R2 log?

Tags: sql-server

Today, for a great oversight, did a deal with a big mistake, which I forgot to put the WHERE keyword in the UPDATE statement...
I searched in the google, I found a lot of things of how to restore the database ( FROM BACKUP ), but the backup was done daily database simply disappeared :(

Now, the only information I have remaining is the log file of SQL, I found the ApexSQL log, that program make a SQL undo script, but, just for a 10th process... I have 2024 to restore, and, I don't want to pay U$ 1.5k for this program, now, I want to know, how I can restore the informations, have a FREE program to make this ?

Comment: database disappeared by an update command ? what was that query, tell me.. please i will also do... :)

Comment: What backups are still available? Are there any? Are you sure the .mdf file(s) are gone forever?!

Comment: thats why I alwaysssssssss use `BEGIN TRAN` for `UPDATE , DELETE` operations :)

Comment: I don't mean to sound like a jerk but maybe you shouldn't be running these sorts of ad hoc UPDATES in a Production environment. Especially outside of a transaction.

Comment: It's times like these that I finally understand why some DBMS are not auto-commit.

Comment: It sounds like you had a bunch of issues stacking up here, and there's not going to be a free way out.  You ran a bad and untested command in production with no transaction or rollback ability, have no backups, and don't want to pay for a fix?  You are going to need to spend money on a tool and very likely a consultant to fix what appear to be issues in your environments.  No backups is a huge red flag here.

Comment: Not sure a consultant could actually save anything if no backups exist. Except [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-D1KVIuvjA), maybe.

Answer (score 2):

There is no free tool to do this. Basically, your only other option is to restore a backup. For that you need to have made a full backup of the database. If you have one, you can recover your table at the time of your full backup by restoring it into another database, and copy the table back to your original database.

Plus, if your database is in full recovery model, you can backup your transaction log and try to restore it after the full backup restore and other transaction log backups that you might have taken in between if you have a backup plan.
So, do you have backups of your database, and when were they taken?